# Untitled runtime error as a title of a Google Search result

Tags: google-chrome, next.js

When I search for my website, the search result looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toIsS.png)

It shows this text instead of the original name and description.

I ran npm run build (The project is Nextjs/Typescript) and the build didn't show me any errors. I checked the pages and everything is alright.

Do you have a clue where this issue may come from?